# Javax.el, ELResolver: Resolve dependencies between variables

Tags: java, variables, jboss, el

iam building a small application to work with variables.
The first step is to resolve simple dependencies between variables.
I can not get things to run properly.
I can resolve very simple declarations like a=10, but it always fails if it gets a little bit more complex like:
a=b; b=10.
I reduced my code to the following few lines:

```
import javax.el.BeanELResolver;
import javax.el.ELContext;
import javax.el.ELResolver;
import javax.el.ExpressionFactory;
import javax.el.FunctionMapper;
import javax.el.ValueExpression;
import javax.el.VariableMapper;

import org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl;
import org.jboss.el.lang.VariableMapperImpl;


public void testEvalutation() throws Exception{

ExpressionFactory factory = new ExpressionFactoryImpl();    
ELContext context = new ELContext() {
  final ELResolver elResolver = new BeanELResolver();
  final VariableMapper variableMapper = new VariableMapperImpl();
  public ELResolver getELResolver() { return elResolver; }
  public FunctionMapper getFunctionMapper() { return null; }
  public VariableMapper getVariableMapper() { return variableMapper; }
};
ValueExpression a = factory.createValueExpression(context, "#{b}", Float.class);
ValueExpression b = factory.createValueExpression(context, "#{c}", Float.class);
ValueExpression c = factory.createValueExpression(context, "#{10}", Float.class);

context.getVariableMapper().setVariable("a",a);
context.getVariableMapper().setVariable("b",b);
context.getVariableMapper().setVariable("c",c);

ValueExpression expression = context.getVariableMapper().resolveVariable("a");
assertEquals(10f,expression.getValue(context));
```

}

The result for 'a' is 0.0.
Is there anything a did wrong or do you know a way i can get my code running?

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: I notice you are only using a [BeanELResolver](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/BeanELResolver.html). Generally you would create a [CompositeELResolver](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/CompositeELResolver.html) as demonstrated in [this blog post](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2008/04/java-using-el-outside-j2ee.html).

Comment: Hi, I have read the example you mentioned and tried a similar evaluation in my code. If i set a=10 and b=5 i can create a expression like ${a+b} which ends up with the correct result: 15. But the example doesnt show how I can link to variables a=b; b=10. Even with a CompositeELResolver I still dont get the right result.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a dig into an EL implementation and it is sensitive to the ordering of expression creation and mapping.

When the [ExpressionFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ExpressionFactory.html) creates a [ValueExpression](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ValueExpression.html) it parses the expression and uses the [VariableMapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/VariableMapper.html) to bind any expressions resolved from there. So when you set **a** it will not resolve **b** because it has not been set yet.

As a result, `#{b}` resolves to *null* which is then coerced to *Float* with a result of *0.0*.

The following code resolves to the value *10.0*:

```
ValueExpression c = factory.createValueExpression(context, "#{10}", Float.class);
context.getVariableMapper().setVariable("c", c);
ValueExpression b = factory.createValueExpression(context, "#{c}", Float.class);
context.getVariableMapper().setVariable("b", b);
ValueExpression a = factory.createValueExpression(context, "#{b}", Float.class);
context.getVariableMapper().setVariable("a", a);

ValueExpression expression = context.getVariableMapper().resolveVariable("a");
System.out.println(expression.getValue(context));
```

Note that this is different to what happens when resolving variables from an [ELResolver](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ELResolver.html).

*I used a different implementation (EL 2.2; Java EE 6 equiv) but I would expect similar behavior in the JBoss implementation.*

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that works like I need it. It doesnt rely on ordering and resolves the variables at any complexity:

```
public class ElVariableResolver extends ELResolver  {
[...]
 protected final HashMap<String, Variable> variablesMap = new HashMap<String, Variable>();

 public ElVariableResolver(final Collection<Variable> variables) {
    this.variables = new HashSet<Variable>(variables);
    Iterator<Variable> iterator = variables.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      Variable v = iterator.next();
      this.variablesMap.put(v.getName(), v);
    }
    [...]
    final FunctionMapperImpl functionMapper = new FunctionMapperImpl();
    this.expressionFactory = new ExpressionFactoryImpl();
    this.elContext = createELContext(this, functionMapper);
  }

 private static ELContext createELContext(final ELResolver resolver, final FunctionMapper functionMapper) {
    return new ELContext() {
      final VariableMapperImpl variableMapper = new VariableMapperImpl();
      @Override
      public ELResolver getELResolver() {
        return resolver;
      }
      @Override
      public FunctionMapper getFunctionMapper() {
        return functionMapper;
      }
      @Override
      public VariableMapper getVariableMapper() {
        return variableMapper;
      }
    };
  }

   public Object getVariableValue(final Variable variable) {
    String el;
    final Class<?> type;
    final String value = variable.getValue();
    switch (variable.getVariableType()) {
      case NUMBER:
        el = value.trim();
        type = Float.class;
        break;
      [...]
      final String expression = String.format("${%s}", el);
      ValueExpression ve = expressionFactory.createValueExpression(this.elContext, expression, type);
      Object result = ve.getValue(this.elContext);
      return result;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
    if ((base == null) && (property != null)) {
      Variable v = this.variablesMap.get(property);
      if (v != null) {
        return this.getVariableValue(v);
      }
    }
    return "TODO"; 
  }
}

public class ElVariableResolverTest extends TestCase{

  private final Variable l = new Variable("L",NUMBER,"M");
  private final Variable m = new Variable("M",NUMBER,"N");
  private final Variable n = new Variable("N",NUMBER,"10");
  private ElVariableResolver resolver;

  public void testEvaluation() {
    final List<Variable> variables = Arrays.asList(l,m,n);
    resolver = new ElVariableResolver(variables);
    assertEquals(new Float(10),resolver.getVariableValue("L"));
  } 
}
```